# Refactor to save bytes?

Tags: code-optimization

I'm a painful 128 bytes of my max for this Trinket. Any refactoring I could do to get down the size?

```c
#include <Adafruit_NeoPixel.h>
#include <Wire.h>
#include <RTClib.h>

#define LEDPIN 1
#define TONE 4
#define BTNPIN 3

RTC_DS1307 rtc;
Adafruit_NeoPixel strip = Adafruit_NeoPixel(5, LEDPIN, NEO_RGB);

const long fadeTime = 10 * 60000L; // X minutes
const int colorStops = 255;
const int delaySpeed = fadeTime / colorStops;
const int notes[] = {262,294,330,349};
const uint32_t alarmLength = 5 * 60000L; // 5 minutes

void setup() {
  rtc.begin();
  rtc.adjust(DateTime(__DATE__, __TIME__));

  pinMode(TONE,OUTPUT);
  pinMode(BTNPIN, INPUT);
  digitalWrite(BTNPIN, HIGH);

  strip.begin();
  strip.show();
}

void loop() {
  DateTime now = rtc.now();

  // If it's 5:10 am on a week day, start the fade in
  if (now.hour() == 5 && now.minute() == 10 && now.second() == 0 && now.dayOfTheWeek() != 1 && now.dayOfTheWeek() != 7){
    // Fade in light
    for(int i = 1; i<colorStops; i++){
      if (kill() == true){ break; }

      for(int np = 0;np<strip.numPixels(); np++){
        strip.setPixelColor(np, strip.Color(i,i,i));
      }
      strip.show();
      delay(delaySpeed);
    }

    // Play tone after light fully bright
    for( uint32_t tStart = millis();  (millis()-tStart) < alarmLength; ){
      if (kill() == true){ break; }

      for(int np = 0;np<strip.numPixels(); np++){
         strip.setPixelColor(np, strip.Color(random(50,255),random(50,255),random(50,255)));
      }
      strip.show();

      beep(notes[random(0,3)]);
      delay(100);
    }

    turnOffPixels();
  }
}

void beep(int delayAmount)
{
  for (uint16_t t = 0; t < 30*1000/2; t += delayAmount)
  {  
    digitalWrite(TONE,HIGH);
    delayMicroseconds(delayAmount);
    digitalWrite(TONE,LOW);
    delayMicroseconds(delayAmount);
  }  
}

void turnOffPixels() {
  for(int np = 0;np<strip.numPixels(); np++){
    strip.setPixelColor(np, strip.Color(0,0,0));
  }
  strip.show();
}

bool kill() {
  if (! digitalRead(BTNPIN)) {
    turnOffPixels();
    return true;
  } else {
    return false;
  }
}
```

Error...

```
Sketch uses 5,438 bytes (102%) of program storage space. Maximum is 5,310 bytes.
Global variables use 97 bytes of dynamic memory.
```

Comment: Have you tried using a lighter NeoPixel library?

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams I wasn't even aware of other NeoPixel libraries...are there any you recommend?

Comment: I use [light_ws2812](https://github.com/cpldcpu/light_ws2812/) myself. Mostly the C library, but I can see the non-Arduino C++ library being useful in your case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the `rtc.adjust(DateTime(__DATE__, __TIME__));`. You only need to set the RTC once, after e.g. you insert the backup battery.

Change

```
pinMode(BTNPIN, INPUT);
digitalWrite(BTNPIN, HIGH);
```

to

```
pinMode(BTNPIN, INPUT_PULLUP);
```

Inline the beep function using the `inline` hint:

```
inline void beep(int delayAmount)
...
```

Shorter `beep` function:

```
inline void beep(int delayAmount)
{
  for (uint16_t t = 0; t < 30*1000; t += delayAmount)
  {  
    digitalWrite(TONE,t & 0x01);// HIGH is odd, LOW if even
    delayMicroseconds(delayAmount);
  }  
}
```

Comment: To inline a function you use the `static` keyword, as the compiler essentially ignores `inline`.

Comment: @EdgarBonet The compiled code got smaller with just the `inline`.

Answer (score 1):

On a quick test build for an ATmega328p type Arduino, the implementation of random() and its unique dependencies seems to be about 180 bytes, so you might see if there's a more compact way of achieving your need there, perhaps using the low byte of some mathematical expression of the time, and just retrying until you get an in-range value.

Of course if you get really stuck, you could remove the bootloader and program it with ISP from an ordinary Arduino or something like that.

Comment: I'm inclined to agree with Chris Stratton here. The Trinket has an Attiny85 on it, which has 8k of program memory. However the amount they need for the bootloader limits the memory available to you somewhat. If you program via ICSP you could use all of the 8k of program memory. But if you don't want that inconvenience, finding another Neopixel library, as Ignacio suggested, could help.

Answer (score 1):

Very good suggestions so far. I have only one to add: instead of
`strip.Color(0,0,0)` use just the constant number 0. This saves a
function call.

Answer (score 0):

For refactoring, consider using a `for` loop that executes twice, once for the  “// Fade in light” section of code, and once for the  “// Play tone after light fully bright” section.  For parts of the code that differ, test the loop index and do one action or the other.

Here are two ways to get rid of a few (eg 54) bytes of code:

1. Instead of

```c
 Adafruit_NeoPixel strip = Adafruit_NeoPixel(5, LEDPIN, NEO_RGB);
 ...
 for(int np = 0;np<strip.numPixels(); np++){
 ...
```

(with three instances of the latter), say something like

```c
enum {numPixels = 5 };
Adafruit_NeoPixel strip = Adafruit_NeoPixel(numPixels, LEDPIN, NEO_RGB);
...
for (byte np=0; np<numPixels; ++np){
...
```

This will save about 40 bytes (10 bytes per `for`, and another 10 probably due to `strip.numPixels()` code not linking).  (Note, the savings is due to getting rid of function calls; the change from `int` to `byte` apparently makes no difference in program size, probably because the compiler optimizes `int` to `byte` where its analysis shows it can do so.)

2. Instead of

```c
if (... && now.dayOfTheWeek() != 1 && now.dayOfTheWeek() != 7){
```

say

```c
if (... && now.dayOfTheWeek()+250>250){
```

which will save 14 bytes.  This works as explained in my answer to your previous question.  However, I've written `+250>250` here instead of the `+249>250` there because according to `RTClib` documentation and `RTClib.cpp` code, `.dayOfTheWeek()` returns 0 for Saturday, rather than 1 as you seem to expect.

3. Possibly inline `beep()`, since you call it only once.

Comment: You mean `if (... && (uint8_t)(now.dayOfTheWeek()+250)>250){`. C.f. my comment to [this answer of yours](http://arduino.stackexchange.com/a/24427).